# $f_n \to f \in L^p$ iff $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_E gf_n = \int_E gf$ for all $g\in L^q$

Tags: real-analysis

I've only recently learned about Riesz Represetnation, so I'm having trouble understanding this proof (from Royden's *Real Analysis*):

[image]

I can see why the RHS is a bounded linear functional on $L^P(E)$ (we can use Holder's inequality for that), but how the iff statement follows from this - I cannot see. My only intuition is to go for something like the  Dominated Convergence Theorem, but it doesn't seem like what Royden was referring to here (and there's no domination here anyway).

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you need to show:  If $f_n \to f$ weakly in $L^p(E)$, then $f_n \to f$ in norm.  Or perhaps you can find a counterexample.  I didn't find such a Proposition 6 is Royden 2nd edition.

Comment: @GEdgar By $f_n \to f$ in norm you mean in the dual norm?

Comment: I mean the same thing as the problem does  when it says $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(E)$, that is: $\big(\int_E|f_n-f|^p\big)^{1/p} \to 0$..